# How do I insert html inside a Radio button label (in Yesod)

Tags: haskell, yesod

My attempt to render html as a label for a radiofieldList has yielded the following error.

```
Handler/Manager.hs:91:32:
No instance for (RenderMessage Scheduler (Handler RepHtml))
  arising from a use of `radioFieldList'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for
  (RenderMessage Scheduler (Handler RepHtml))
In the first argument of `mreq', namely `(radioFieldList bPairs)'
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  (jobRes, jobView) <- mreq
                         (radioFieldList bPairs) "Scheduled Jobs" Nothing
In the expression:
  do { let bPairs = buttonPairs kjPairs
           statusPairs
             = map (pack . show &&& id) $ ([minBound .. maxBound] :: [Status            ]);
       (jobRes, jobView) <- mreq
                              (radioFieldList bPairs) "Scheduled Jobs" Nothing;
       (noteRes, noteView) <- mreq textareaField " Notes " Nothing;
       (statusRes, statusView) <- mreq
                                    (selectFieldList statusPairs) " Status " Nothing;
       .... }
```

So, given the code below, does it make sense to create an instance for `(RenderMessage Scheduler (Handler RepHtml))`

```
statusForm :: RForm CapturedData
statusForm kjPairs extra = do
let bPairs = buttonPairs kjPairs
    statusPairs = map (pack . show &&& id) $
                  ([minBound .. maxBound] :: [Status])
(jobRes ,jobView) <- mreq (radioFieldList bPairs) "Scheduled Jobs" Nothing
(noteRes, noteView) <- mreq textareaField " Notes " Nothing
(statusRes, statusView) <- mreq (selectFieldList statusPairs) " Status " Nothing    -- as of 0.9.4.x it is just best to explicitly type widgetFile
let widget = toWidget ($(widgetFile "status") :: Widget)
return (CapturedData <$> jobRes <*> statusRes  <*> noteRes
       , widget)

buttonPairs :: [KeyJobPair] -> [(Handler RepHtml,KeyJobPair)]
buttonPairs kjList = sort $ map buttonPairs' kjList
  where buttonPairs' :: KeyJobPair -> (Handler RepHtml,KeyJobPair)
    buttonPairs' (KeyJobPair ((Key key), JobData (Firmware product)
                                           (Version version)
                                           (StartDate sDate)
                                            status)) =
      let (Right jid) = fromPersistValue key :: Either Text Int64
      in (hamletToRepHtml [hamlet|<a href=@{RootR}(" Job Id " ++ (show jid))>|]
         ,KeyJobPair (Key key, JobData (Firmware product)
                                       (Version version)
                                       (StartDate sDate)
                                       status))
```

It occurred to me, the true answer is to create a custom Field that will accept `(HTML,a)`, as opposed to the required `(msg,a)` `radioFieldList` wants. I'm hoping that just creating an instance for `RenderMessage` will work.

Comment: What is the library you are working with? It's really not obvious from the context.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to call `hamletToRepHtml` there, why not `renderHtml` from `Text.Hamlet`?

I don't have yesod installed on this machine (so I can't verify), but that should point you in the right direction. I'm assuming you don't want that to be a widget, and that you just want it rendered.